# Downside(s) of using HTTPs only on parts of the site

Tags: performance, apache, http, https, magento-1.7

I am managing a shop that forces HTTPs on the register/login/account/checkout pages, but that's it, and I've been trying to convince people to force HTTPs on everything.

I know that it's recommended to use HTTPs everywhere, but not sure why.

Are there any good reasons to keep part of the site on HTTP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good reason is that page perfomance has a massive impact on sales (there's lots of published studies) and SSL has a BIG imact on performance - particularly if it's not tuned right.

But running a mixed SSL and non-SSL is full of pitfalls for the unwary...

Exactly which pages you put inside SSL has a big impact on security too though - suppose you send a login form using HTTP with a POST target which is HTTPS - a trivial analysis would suggest this is secure - but in fact an MITM could modify the login page to send the post elsewhere or inject some ajax to fork a request to a different location.

Further with mixed HTTP and HTTPS you've got the problem of transferring sessions securely - the user fills their session-linked shopping basket outside the SSL site, then pays for it inside the SSL site - how do you prevent session fixation problems in the transition?

Hence I'd only suggest running a mixed site if you've got really expert skills in HTTP - and since you're asking *this* question here, that rather implies you don't.

A compromise solution is to use SPDY. SPDY requires SSL but makes most sites (especially ones that have not been heavily performance optimized) much faster. Currently it's not supported by MSIE - and (last time I checked) is not enabled by default in Firefox. But it's likely to make up a large part of HTTP/2.0 any time soon.

Using (good) CDNs over HTTPS also mitigates much of the performance impact of SSL.

Answer (score -1):

There's really no need to use HTTPS on the whole website. Using HTTPS will cause the server to consume more resources as it has to do extra work to encrypt and decrypt the connection, not to mention extra steps/handshake in negotiating algorithms etc.

If you have a heavy traffic website, the performance hit can be quite big.

This will also mean a slow response time then using plain on HTTP.

You should only really use HTTPS on the parts of the site you actually need to be secure, such as when ever the user send important information to your site, completes forms, logs in, private parts of the site etc.

One other issue can be if you use resources from none secure URLS, maybe images/scripts hosted elsewhere. If they are not available over HTTPS then your visitors will get a warning about an insecure connection.

You also need to realise the fact HTTPS data/pages will hardly ever get cached. this will also add a performance penalty.

Comment: The performance overhead on the server is *very* small (unless you use some specific ephemeral Diffie-Hellman cyphers). As for browsers not supporting SSL - I'm in 2013 : When are you?

Comment: the performance hit can be quite big if you have a high traffic website, consuming more ram and CPU cycles. you WILL notice a difference on high traffic websites, I've run enough of them to knoq.

Comment: I must be doing it wrong then. I see less than 5% CPU usage overhead with SSL.

Comment: -1 your authentication cookie will be included with every request whether you need it or not. This means every request you serve over HTTP instead of HTTPS is vulnerable to session hijacking.